# C# return json result as an array which is not required

Tags: c#, json, .net, asp.net-core-webapi

I am creating .net core web api application for employee management and i have written api using controller.
I want get by id method to return data in json object and not in array.

My code looks like this :

```
       [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public JsonResult Get(int id)
    {
        string query = @"select EmployeeId,EmployeeFirstName,EmployeeLastName,EmployeeEmail,EmployeeGender,(select DepartmentName from Department where DepartmentId =Employee.Emp_DepartmentId) as DepartmentName,(select DesignationName from Designation where DesignationId=Employee.Emp_DesignationId) as DesignationName,EmployeeDob from Employee where EmployeeId = @EmployeeId ";
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        string sqlDataSource = _configuration.GetConnectionString("Dbconn");
        SqlDataReader myReader;
        using (SqlConnection myCon = new SqlConnection(sqlDataSource))
        {
            myCon.Open();
            using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myCon))
            {
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeId", id);
                myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
                table.Load(myReader);
                myReader.Close();
                myCon.Close();
            }
        }
        return new JsonResult(table);
    }
```

And its giving output like this :

```
   [
    {
    "EmployeeId": 1,
    "EmployeeFirstName": "abcd",
    "EmployeeLastName": "abcd",
    "EmployeeEmail": "abcd@abcd.com",
    "EmployeeGender": "abcd",
    "EmployeeDoj": "1995-01-01T00:00:00",
    "DepartmentName": "abcd",
    "DesignationName": "abcd",
    "EmployeeDob": "1995-01-01T00:00:00"
    }
   ]
```

but i want output like this :

```
{
"EmployeeId": 1,
"EmployeeFirstName": "abcd",
"EmployeeLastName": "abcd",
"EmployeeEmail": "abcd@abcd.com",
"EmployeeGender": "abcd",
"EmployeeDoj": "1995-01-01T00:00:00",
"DepartmentName": "abcd",
"DesignationName": "abcd",
"EmployeeDob": "1995-01-01T00:00:00"
}
```

Comment: Using `DataTable`s will do that. It would be better to read the data into an object and return that. Possibly using an ORM, or just manually mapping the data.

Comment: Return the first row (DataRow) of the table. I've newer worked with DataSets/DataTables and JSON web services, but I'm guessing it should work (I haven't worked with DataSets/DataTables in about a decade. You'll be happier with a real ORM

Answer (score 0):

In your case the variable `table` represents your table in database. It's a collection (array), that's why the JSON output is in `[]` braces. You probably want to get the first and only element from the table and then return that as a JSON.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be convert DataTable to array of objects and return the first array object as json

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

 return new JsonResult(JArray.FromObject(dt)[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want get by id method to return data in json object and not in
> array.

As you are using `datatable` so no matter how you return it would be within `[]` array. In fact, if you use `DataRow row = table.Rows[0];`
it will ended up with the same output within `[]`. However, you could use `while loop` on `Data Reader`. You could follow below example:

**Using Ado.Net Data Reader:**

```
        [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult GetSingleData(int id)
        {
            var printer = new PrinterJob();
            string query = " SELECT [PrinterId] ,[PrinterName],[PrintedBy],[TotalPrint] FROM [Attendance].[dbo].[PrintJob] WHERE PrinterId = @PrinterId";
            string sqlDataSource = "Server=ServerName; Database=DatabaseName;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true";
            SqlDataReader myReader;
            using (SqlConnection myCon = new SqlConnection(sqlDataSource))
            {
                myCon.Open();
                using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myCon))
                {
                    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PrinterId", id);
                    myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
                    while (myReader.Read())
                    {

                        printer.PrinterId = (int)myReader["PrinterId"]; // Remember Type Casting is required here it has to be according to database column data type
                        printer.PrinterName = myReader["PrinterName"].ToString();
                        printer.PrintedBy = (int)myReader["PrintedBy"];
                        printer.TotalPrint = (int)myReader["TotalPrint"];

                    }
                    myReader.Close();
                    myCon.Dispose();
                    myCon.Close();
                }
            }
            return new JsonResult(printer);
        }
```

**Note:** You can use `Return ok(printer)` as well which also `Json` data. Moreover, I have tested with `PrintJob` table because of easy reproducible reason, Therefore, you can use your own `table` along with your `query`. Just reply that and will work as expected.

**Output:**

[image]

[image]